# java.lang.UnsatifsiedLinkError at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method) with Tess4J

Tags: java, windows, tesseract

I have a small application that takes a screenshot, crops a certain area and then uses OCR on that image.

I've compiled the code to a .jar file and it works fine on OS X but when I run it on Windows XP I get the following error:

[image: cmd screenshot]

I've installed Tesseract on Windows XP using [this url](http://domasofan.spdns.eu/tesseract/) and it works fine. I've tried adding `-Djna.library.path=${workspace_loc:/SonicScreenshot}/dlls/x86` as a `VM Run/Debug configuration` but this doesn't work as well.

What else could I try?

Comment: Your screenshot shows you running from the command prompt, but isn't the "VM Run/Debug configuration" an option within Eclipse?

Comment: Do you have VC++ runtime installed?